# Azure data Factory - write result of pipeline to REST API?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

While I've seen examples of getting data from HTTP, I haven't really seen once for outputting to a REST API.

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks,
-Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the web activity in ADFv2. It offers GET, POST and PUT methods.

In ADFv1 you'd need to write a custom activity to interact with the API.

Hope this helps.